# Does $\gcd(a, bc) = 1$ imply $\gcd(a, b) = 1$?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Assuming $a, b, c > 1$, then $(a, bc) = 1$ implies $b \not\mid a$, for if $b \mid a$, then we'd have $1 = (a, bc) \geq b > 1$ which is a contradiction. Likewise, $(a, bc) = 1$ also implies $c \not\mid a$.

So $b > 1$ and $(a, bc) = 1$ implies $b \not\mid a$ which implies $(a, b) < b > 1$. Can it be shown also that $(a, b) = 1$?

Comment: If $a$ and $bc$ do not have any nontrivial divisor, then  $a$ and $b$ do not have common divisor.

Comment: If $d \mid b$ then clearly $d \mid bc$.

Comment: More generally, $\,\gcd(a,b) \mid \gcd(a,bc)\,$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it:

If $d \mid a, b$, then $d \mid a, bc$. The contrapositive is "if $d \not\mid a, bc$, then $d \not\mid a, b$. From $(a, bc) = 1$, we know $d > 1 \not\mid a, bc$, therefore $d > 1 \not\mid a, b$, therefore $(a, b) = 1$.

Comment: By the dupe: $\,a\mid a,\ b\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\, (a,b)\mid (a,bc) = 1\ \ $